# Get first 5 elements from a vector

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, collections

I am having a `Vector` in my `multithreaded` env  and i need to get its first 5 elements to pass to a `threadpool`

. is there any best practice around this ? ( i mean using java util classes )

I can do it inside a `synchronized` block and loop through the vector until i find the first 5 elements. i am wondering is that the correct way to do it.

please advice me.

UPDATED SECTION ------

please find my actual problem i need to solve.

1. class A will have a vector ( sorted according to the priority. this will update in heigh frequency. i need to get the first 5 elements)
2. class B will have the `myOwnThreadPool` that extend the `java.util.ThreadPoolExecutor` and override it's `afterExecute` method. (pool size will be 5 )
3. class A will get the first 5 elements from the vector and send it to the class B pool to process.
4. once `afterExecute` method notified that one thread is returned i will pick the first most element from the `vector` ( in class A / with the most priority ) and send it to the pool to process.

I think now my question gives a better idea for you all.

Thank you all for the answers/guidance and further suggestions are very much welcome.

Comment: Is it still being modified?  Might its size go below 5?

Comment: `Vector` is thread safe.., what is your concern?

Comment: @LouisWasserman - nop it will be 5 or some configurable integer.

Comment: @Rosdi- my concern is about the java best practice how to do this.

Comment: Like @LouisWasserman hints, you are not providing enough info really.  What triggers this 'submit first 5 to pool' activity?  Could it be that that there are less than 5 items in the vector whe n the activity is triggered? ? Does it need to happen when the item count reaches 5?  If you do not give a lot of info with these multithreaded questions, you are likely to get sub-optimal answers:)

Comment: @MartinJames - Thank you for the comment. i edited the question. hope i am doing the correct thing.

Answer (score 6):

`Vector` offers a [`subList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) method, which you can use as follows:

```
List five = myVector.subList(0, 5);
```

This does not make a copy of the element, only builds a view into the vector. You could add copying as follows:

```
List five = new List();
Collections.copy(five, myVector.subList(0, 5));
```

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use Vector. Please consider using `Collections.synchronizedList()` to create synchronized list.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
      ...
  synchronized(list) {
      Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
      while (i.hasNext())
          foo(i.next());
  }
```

Comment: @Garbadge - Thanks for the answer. i just got to know about this `synchronizedList`.